# How can I give rewards only after successful completion of IAP

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I will try and explain my issue as clearly as i can. I have IAP in my app, i am trying to use boolean values to determine if the player should receive rewards or not. I am using this code

```
self.purchaseExtraRounds = true
self.purchaseRemoveAds = true
```

but i am not sure where to place it to enable the user to get the rewards only after the purchase has been completed. At the moment wherever i seem to place it, i can click on a IAP and then click cancel and the rewards have been enabled without actually purchasing it. Here is my IAP manager file.

```
class IAPManager: NSObject {
  static let shared = IAPManager()
    var purchaseExtraRounds = false
    var purchaseRemoveAds = false
    
  private override init() {
    super.init()
  }
  
  func getProducts() {
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: allInAppPurchases)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
  }
  
  func purchase(product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
    if !IAPManager.shared.canMakePayments() {
        return false
    } else {
      let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }
    return true
  }

  func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
    return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
  }
}

extension IAPManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKRequestDelegate {

  func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    let badProducts = response.invalidProductIdentifiers
    let goodProducts = response.products
    
    if !goodProducts.isEmpty {
      ProductsDB.shared.items = response.products
        print("Good", ProductsDB.shared.items)
    }
    
    print("Bad", badProducts)
  }
  
  func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("didFailWithError ", error)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      print("purchase failed")
    }
  }
  
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      print("request did finish ")
    }
  }
}

final class ProductsDB: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
  static let shared = ProductsDB()
  var items: [SKProduct] = [] {
    willSet {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.objectWillChange.send()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tired placing the code in several places in this file but i’m hitting a wall.

Comment: You need to observe transactions of SKPaymentQueue with your observer, and do that once payment transaction completed. Made product request does not mean yet that money will be paid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the issue like this; implement this function

```
private func handlePurchase(_ id: String) {
        if id == "remove ads product id" {
            removeAds(id: "remove ads product id")}
}
```

call at this point

```
case .purchased:
               handlePurchase(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
```

which will call another function i created to give the reward like so

```
func removeAds(id: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "RemoveAdsPurchased")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start observing inside AppDelegate when your App finished with launching.

You have to call

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self) //<< here comes your observer
```

inside your IAPManager.

Then your purchase() function can be called correctly. Then adopt the

```
SKPaymentTransactionObserver
```

protocol, where you can implement the following method:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
```

Here you get your transactions, and a `transaction.transactionState` which indicates whether your transaction was successful.

Back to your original question, if your state is purchased, you will set your variable accordingly which product was bought

Comment: Thank you @davidev i understand now why i was having that issue then. So far I have implemented that code but not getting any result. I have added the reward to the purchase successful state. i will take some time to figure that out then.

Comment: Ok so i'm now implementing my IAP correctly thank you. I have six IAP items and i am not sure how to call the correct method to the specific IAP that was requested when it gets to the purchased state. Any suggestions? Here is a list of the methods i'm calling.
            case .purchased:
                removeAds()
                roundsx5()
                roundsx30()
                roundsx70()
                roundsx400()
                roundsx1000()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)